# How to implement Generic reducer and action in NgRx

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm working on a Angular 9 app that uses the NGRX store and I'm new to NgRx. Could some one let me know how to develop a generic reducer/action where we don't need to write reducer and actions again and again. For an example I have userList and productLst which has similar kind of actions then how do we implement one generic list reducer/action and use it for both(userList and productLst)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, to distinguish states, entities and actions every feature should have own state, reducers and actions.

But you can use `@ngrx/data` to reduce boilerplate: https://ngrx.io/guide/data

There's `EntityCollectionServiceFactory` that will create reducers and actions for you.

```js
constructor(EntityCollectionServiceFactory: EntityCollectionServiceFactory) {
  this.heroService = EntityCollectionServiceFactory.create<Hero>('Hero');
  this.filteredHeroes$ = this.heroService.filteredEntities$;
  this.loading$ = this.heroService.loading$;
}

getHeroes() { this.heroService.getAll(); }
add(hero: Hero) { this.heroService.add(hero); }
deleteHero(hero: Hero) { this.heroService.delete(hero.id); }
update(hero: Hero) { this.heroService.update(hero); }
```

More info here: https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-collection-service#examples-from-the-demo-app